# Filter table using values in specific column

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

I am trying to filter a table using javascript to only show rows which have more then 5 seeders. Here is a link to a JSFiddle with an example of the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/xQB4Z/566/

Example of one row:

```
<td align=left width=500><NOBR><a href="download.php?id=1241487&SSL=1"><img style="position: relative; top: 2px;" src="themes/classic/pic/download.gif.pagespeed.ce.6SI31hDpjb.gif" border="0"></a>&nbsp;<a class="index" href="details.php?id=1241487&amp;hit=1">CENTOS 4</a> (<b><font color="red">NEW!</font></b>)</NOBR><br/><font size=1 color='666666'><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Uploaded 13 m, 44 seconds after pre</i></font></td>
<td align="right"><b><a href="details.php?id=1241487&amp;hit=1&amp;filelist=1">78</a></b></td>
<td align="right">0</td>
<td align=center><nobr>2016-08-17<br/>23:23:27</nobr></td>
<td align=center>----</td>
<td align=center>6.64<br/>GB</td>
<td align=center>----</td>
<td align="right"><span class="green">2</span></td>
<td align="right"><span class="green">2</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach(function(v, k){
    var seeders = v.querySelectorAll("td")[8].textContent;
    if(seeders < 5){
        v.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

What this will do is to check the content of 9th column in each row and if the value in this column is smaller then 5, hide the row.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ajm0e4xk/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I add another element to the page it seems to break the code. Could you possibly help me out again?
http://jsfiddle.net/ajm0e4xk/

Comment: @JamiePeregrym `v.querySelectorAll("td")[8]` means the 9th column, just change `[8]` to the column's position minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something simple to get you started:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("yourTableId").querySelectorAll("tr");

for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { // start at row 1 to skip header
  if (+rows[i].cells[8].textContent <= 5)
    rows[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xQB4Z/568/

Note: I gave your table an id. You could instead use `document.querySelector("table")` to just get the first table on the page.

Comment: How would one go about using "document.querySelector("table")" on a page with two tables like here http://jsfiddle.net/ajm0e4xk/7/

Comment: `document.querySelector("table")` will select the first table on the page. If you want the second table you can use `document.querySelectorAll("table")[1]` (where the number in square brackets is a zero-based index - and note the addtion of `All` in the function name). But if you're going to be referring to them from JS it would be better to give them IDs so that the code doesn't break if the layout of the page changes.